# How to deactivate window restoration?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument, nspersistentdocument

I am using SDK 10.8.

I am subclassing `NSPersistentDocument` (but the question might interest people sublassing `NSDocument`) and I want to deactivate the window restoration. So far, here is what I have done :

```
-(void)restoreStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    NSLog(@"No 1") ;
}


-(void)restoreDocumentWindowWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
                                     state:(NSCoder *)state
                         completionHandler:(void (^)(NSWindow *, NSError *))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"No 2") ;
}
```

The problem is that when I try in my application to create a new document, no window is shown.

**What is the proper way to desactivate the window restoration ?**

Comment: Is this just for testing purposes? If so, there's a better way to do that that doesn't involve mucking with your code.

Comment: This function of window restoration makes my app unlaunchable, for instance after a crash (or I click stop in `xcode`). I don't want the users of my app to face the same problem and be unable to launch anymore the app. Therefore, I want to deactivate this function. But, if you have better, it's great !

Comment: That should only be true if your stored state is corrupt or you've changed the keys you store it under. In normal circumstances, state restoration exists to save user data (that they haven't manually saved) in the event of a crash—your users will *want* it to be there when the app crashes on them. For debugging purposes, you can disable state restoration in your Xcode scheme: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zQAR4.png

Comment: @PeterHosey you can add your comment as an answer if you want!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This function of window restoration makes my app unlaunchable, for instance after a crash (or I click stop in xcode). I don't want the users of my app to face the same problem and be unable to launch anymore the app.

That should only be true if your stored state is corrupt or you've changed the keys you store it under.

In normal circumstances, state restoration exists to save user data (that they haven't manually saved) in the event of a crash—your users will *want* it to be there when the app crashes on them.

For debugging purposes, you can disable state restoration in your Xcode scheme:

[image: In Xcode 4's scheme editor, for the Run verb, on the Options tab, check the “Launch application without state restoration” checkbox.]

Answer (score 0):

The following works, but I have to admit that I don't know why exactly !!

```
-(void)restoreDocumentWindowWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
                                     state:(NSCoder *)state
                         completionHandler:(void (^)(NSWindow *, NSError *))completionHandler 
{
    DDLogWarn(@"Method 'restoreDocumentWindowWithIdentifier...' overidden") ;

    [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] newDocument:nil] ;
}


- (void)restoreStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder 
{
    DDLogWarn(@"Method 'restoreStateWithCoder...' overidden") ;

    [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] newDocument:nil] ;
}
```